# Change random image every midnight

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm have some images on the app and I want that the image change random every day at midnight.

I've tried unsuccessfully to do that in the code below, but can't figure how to make it work.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSDateFormatter *formater = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [formater setDateFormat:@"EEE         dd-MM-yyyy' "];
    timeLabel.text = [formater stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    timerIsCount = NO;

    [self updateTimer];

}



-(void)datePic
{
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5 target:self       selector:@selector(randomCard) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)updateTimer
{
    NSCalendar *calender = [[NSCalendar       alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
unsigned int unitFlag = NSDayCalendarUnit;
NSDateComponents *components = [calender components:unitFlag     fromDate:0];
   int day = [components day];

if (day) {
    //[self randomCard];
   }

 }
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code-writing site. You need to have a go at writing this and then return when you have a specific problem. Following a few tutorials would be helpful as well. If you are unclear about how to ask questions on Stack Overflow, there is an FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: "i try to do that". Then show what you tried so you can be corrected where you went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have to a take array of images. And one int value.

You want every night your image will change, so you have to set timer 
Here **Slidingimageview is imageview**

> NSInteger index=0;
>
> arrslidingimages=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"01.png",@"02.png",@"03.png",@"04.png",@"05.png"@"06.png",@"07.png",nil];
>
> -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
>
> [super viewDidAppear:animated];
>       //       Animation of sliding image
>
> slideTransition = [CATransition animation];
>
> CATransition * slideTransition; //instance variable
>
> slideTransition.duration = 1.0;
>
> slideTransition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
>
> slideTransition.type = kCATransitionFade;
>
> slideTransition.delegate = self;
>
> [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60*60*24 target:self selector:@selector(changeImage:)  userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
>
> }
>
> -(void)changeImage:(NSTimer *)timer
>    {
>
> //change timer of the sling image and set the current page of page controller
>
> slideTransition.subtype =kCATransitionFromRight; // or kCATransitionFromRight
>
> [_Slidingimageview.layer addAnimation:slideTransition forKey:nil];
>
> index++;
>
> if(index==[arrslidingimages count]){
>       index=0;
>       }
>
> _Slidingimageview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[arrslidingimages objectAtIndex:index]];
>
> }

You have to set timer of midnight by finding time in seconds. If you want more random images then Add those images in array

NOTE: Right now in code I set default value like when u run app this timer starts(EXA. If you run app at 12:00 AM today then image will change at 12:00 AM tomorrow)

Hope this thing Works

Comment: i will try it 
Thank you